# Whitelist a resource in cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, amazon-rds

I am working with cloudformation. I am creating a security group for RDS and trying to white list the EC2 private ip. But it is failed to create security group

```
  TestSecuri:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    DependsOn: EC2Instance
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: allow connections from specified CIDR ranges
      SecurityGroupIngress:
      - IpProtocol: tcp
        FromPort: 800
        ToPort: 800
        CidrIp: !GetAtt "EC2Instance.PrivateIp/32"
```

Comment: @Paolo its not working

Comment: What error do you see? It works for me

Answer (score 0):

You can just do with `Sub`:

```
CidrIp: !Sub "{EC2Instance.PrivateIp}/32"
```